# Sum must equal 10000

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

I was wondering if there is a way to make a formula to automatically adjust so that the sum of a column doesn't a certain maximum.

For example: I want to contribute $10,000 to a charity, taking 10% of my income. My income varies per month, so I will probably hit the $10,000 limit earlier. For simplicity's sake, 10% of my income (in a perfect world):

- Jan - $2500
- Feb - $2500
- Mar - $4000
- Apr - $3000
- May - who cares.

I'll hit the $10K in April and I'll go over.

Is there a function either at the final sum cell or within the individual months to not have to manually correct each month?

Comment: I don't understand: This seems like a simple case of 12 empty columns with the sum in the 13th column. Or do I misunderstand the problem?

Comment: How your input data looks like? What is your desired output?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `MIN` function to limit a month's charity to no more than what is needed to reach the $10,000 maximum for the year.

For example, if the income for each month is in the range B2:B13 and charity is to go in C2:C13, you can enter the following formula in cell C2 and copy it to the other cells in C2:C13.

```
=MIN(B2*10%,10000-SUM(C$1:C1))
```

The formula will return the lower of:

- 10% of the month's income
- The difference between 10,000 and the sum of the charity amounts from all previous months in the year.

[image]

Comment: It was part of a more complex spreadsheet so I needed to use: =min(B2*10%,MAX(0,10000-sum(C$1:C!), but I think I got it!!!